# Não consigo pegar a data na tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-html

Estou fazendo o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT h.h_dia FROM hh h WHERE h.h_dia = 20180621 GROUP BY h.h_dia
```

Comment: caso o formato do campo h_dia seja DATE e não INT tente mudar o filtro de data para: h.h_dia = '2018-06-21'

Comment: Não retorna nada da tabela

Comment: Como está o valor na coluna h_dia? E qual o tipo da coluna na tabela?

Comment: 2017-07-03 08:00:00 assim por exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu select deve ser assim:

```
SELECT h.h_dia FROM hh h WHERE cast(h.h_dia as date) = '2018-06-21' GROUP BY h.h_dia;
```

Quando o campo é data e hora, se você por no filtro apenas a data ele vai entender que a hora é 00:00:00 e não irá retornar corretamente, então como você quer filtrar apenas pela data, você deve converter o campo apenas para data.

Caso você queira filtrar por data e hora faça da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT h.h_dia FROM hh h WHERE h.h_dia = '2018-06-21 10:45:00' GROUP BY h.h_dia;
```